# easyadmin entity field's dynamic custom choices

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

Installed easyadminbundle with symfony 4, configured for an entity name `Delivery` and it has a field associated to another entity name `WeeklyMenu`:

easy_amin.yaml:

```
Delivery:
...
      form:
        fields:
          - { property: 'delivered'}
          - { property: 'weeklyMenu', type: 'choice', type_options: { choices: null }}
```

I need a **dynamically filtered results** of `weeklyMenu` entity here, so I can get a list of the next days menus and so on. It's set to `null` now but have to get a filtered result here.

I've read about overriding the `AdminController` which I stucked with it. I believe that I have to override easyadmin's query builder that listing an associated entity's result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've figured out, here is the solution if someone looking for:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\EasyAdminController;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class AdminController extends EasyAdminController {

  public function createDeliveryEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view) {
    $formBuilder = parent::createEntityFormBuilder($entity, $view);
    $fields = $formBuilder->all();
    /**
     * @var  $fieldId string
     * @var  $field FormBuilder
     */
    foreach ($fields as $fieldId => $field) {
      if ($fieldId == 'weeklyMenu') {
        $options = [
            'attr'     => ['size' => 1,],
            'required' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'class'    => 'App\Entity\WeeklyMenu',
        ];
        $options['query_builder'] = function (EntityRepository $er) {
          $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('e');

          return $qb->where($qb->expr()->gt('e.date', ':today'))
                    ->setParameter('today', new \DateTime("today"))
                    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('e.delivery', ':true'))
                    ->setParameter('true', 1)
                    ->orderBy('e.date', 'DESC');
        };
        $formBuilder->add($fieldId, EntityType::class, $options);
      }
    }

    return $formBuilder;
  }
}
```

so the easyAdmin check if a formbuilder exists with the entity's name i.e. `create<ENTITYNAME>FormBuilder();` and you can override here with your own logic.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to this would be to create new FormTypeConfigurator and overwrite choices and/or labels. And tag it as:

```
App\Form\Type\Configurator\UserTypeConfigurator:
    tags: ['easyadmin.form.type.configurator']
```

and the configurator looks like this:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Form\Type\Configurator;

use App\Entity\User;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Form\Type\Configurator\TypeConfiguratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormConfigInterface;

final class UserTypeConfigurator implements TypeConfiguratorInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configure($name, array $options, array $metadata, FormConfigInterface $parentConfig)
    {
        if ($parentConfig->getData() instanceof User) {
            $options['choices'] = User::getUserStatusAvailableChoices();
        }

        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function supports($type, array $options, array $metadata)
    {
        return in_array($type, ['choice', ChoiceType::class], true);
    }
}
```